# Is this the same as enough?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adjectives

> This causes a significant reaction to break down the particles.

Is the word "significant" playing the same role as "sufficient" or "enough" vis-à-vis the *to infinitive*?

Comment: Could you perhaps rephrase the last four words of your question?

Comment: "vis-a-vis" is not something natives use regularly.

Comment: Is my usage wrong, Frost?

Answer (score 1):

No, "significant" cannot be substituted with "sufficient" or "enough" in your sentence.  Let me use an easier example to explain..."The new manager made significant changes to our work procedures."  This means that the changes were major, big, substantial.  Sufficient would mean the changes were nothing special but provided only what was needed.  Enough would not make sense in your example sentence or in mine.